# python -- grabbing email attachments to disk?

Tags: python, linux, email, email-attachments

I have a bunch of 500 emails, each with attachments.

I'd like to write a python script that would scroll through all email messages, and saves these attachments to disk. How do I go about it?

Also, suppose I could choose which email program will be used to retrieve the messages from the POP3 server -- would it be best to use `Evolution?` `Thunderbird?` some other program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use an e-mail client to get your e-mail, not when Python has a perfectly cromulent [poplib](http://docs.python.org/library/email) module and also an [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email) module for parsing out the attachments.

Comment: so it does not matter which client I use? how does it know what was the date the email was received on, who sent it, what is the attachment name etc?

Comment: how do I then 'direct' the code to the 'email' file (where presumably all data is stored)?

Comment: You've embiggened this question with your cromulent answer.

Comment: You don't have to use a mail file, you can just grab it directly from the server with the `poplib` module. If you want to read it from an existing client's mail store, that should be fairly easy too as long as the client uses standard mbox format (Thunderbird does, for example). Python has a [mailbox](http://docs.python.org/library/mailbox.html) module for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
with io.open('emails.txt', 'w') as file:
      for email in elist:  file.write(email)
```

Comment: I don't understand. How does your code grab the email exactly? how does it connect to the email client?

Comment: It inferring you have already saved the emails in memory to a list, http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html should help you find your way about getting them into memory.